# Formatting drive as XFS on Centos 5.5

Tags: centos, filesystems, xfs, mkfs

We've got a Centos 5.5 server with 2 array's. One is standard ext3 mounted as /, the other is an SSD array that we are attempting to format as XFS before moving our MySQL database to it.

I've partitioned the SSD array as /dev/sdb1, but when attempting to run mkfs.xfs, I get:

```
mkfs.xfs -f /dev/sdb1
size 0 of data subvolume is too small, minimum 100 blocks
```

When running with the minimum 100 blocks:

```
mkfs.xfs -d size=100b /dev/sdb1 -f
size 100b specified for data subvolume is too large, maximum is 0 blocks
```

I've installed all the required XFS modules, including the kernel mod and xfsprogs. Running mkfs.xfs with just about any option results in the above behavior.

Comment: What does `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` say?

Answer (score 1):

In your original attempt, you created only an extended partition. This is not enough, as this partition type is only a container for more logical partitions. This was made necessary by the limit of 4 partitions the DOS MBR orginally had.

After creating the extended partition, `fdisk` will offer to create logical partitions inside it, starting with a number of 5 when you choose `n` again.

For more infos, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record).